# woocommerce - send order email notification to customer approval

Tags: email, woocommerce, notifications, orders

I'm building an e-commerce site using woocommerce, my business is like Business to Business (B2B).
There is a lot of company that will use my system, every company will have one "Approval" and have many user for customer, So, if my customer (which mean an employee of some company) buy my products from my e-commerce website, I want the email order notification sent to my customer boss who will approve their order.

is there any plugins for this? or if I need to do some code adding on PHP function, how can i do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I am not 100% sure I understand. It is relatively easy to change the recipient of the new order emails, but how do you know which products belong to which company? and/or how do you determine the customer's boss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a request a quote plugin:

http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-request-a-quote/6460218

Than you can just setup the above plugin, and integrate with gravity forms if needed to customize the send to email and other needed forms.